# Is connectedness needed in this statement?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**Suppose $M$ is a arcwise connected metric space, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are  mutually separated in $M$. Let $f_i:A_1\cup A_2\to M$ for $i=$1,2 be two continuous functions such that $f_0|$$A_i$ ($f_0$ restricted to $A_i$) is homotopic to $f_1|A_i$ for $i=$1,2. Then  $f_0$ is homotopic to $f_1$**

- [Here is the link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html) about arcwise connectedness.
- Two sets A and B in a metric space are said to be mutually separated if They are disjoint and open in their union $A\cup B$
- [Here is the link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homotopy.html) about homotopy

My question is

***"Is arcwise connectedness really needed here to prove the above statement ?"***

It seems arcwise connectedness is dispensable by below argument

Since $f_0|A_i$ homotopic to $f_1|A_i$, for $i=1,2$
There exists homotopy,
$F_i:A_i×[0,1]\to M$ for $i=1,2$

Now define, $F:A_1\cup A_2×[0,1]\to M$ as
$F(x,t)= \begin{cases} F_1(x,t),& \text{if } x\in A_1\\ F_2(x,t), & otherwise \end{cases} $

Here $F$ is well defined since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint.
Also $F$ is a homotopy here irrespective of $M$ being arcwise connected.

Am I correct ?

Comment: You do need the fact that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are separated to infer continuity of $F$, but apart from that your argument is right. Arcwise connectedness is not relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  The assumption that $M$ is arcwise connected is completely irrelevant (as is the assumption that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are subsets of $M$, and the assumption that $M$ is a metric space).  The way I would state the result with no irrelevant hypotheses would be:

> Let $X$ and $M$ be topological spaces and $f_0,f_1:X\to M$ be continuous.  Suppose $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$, and that $f_0|_{A_i}$ is homotopic to $f_1|_{A_i}$ for $i=1,2$.  Then $f_0$ is homotopic to $f_1$.

Comment: The $A_i$ don't need to be open in $X$, they just need to be open in $A_1 \cup A_2$.

Comment: $X$ is just my name for $A_1\cup A_2$ (notice that I assume their union is $X$).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I think you've thrown a little bit of the baby out with the bath-water.  I'd guess it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I think rather I've rescued the baby who was hidden and submerged in the bath-water.  In typical applications, it's not that you start out with $A_1$ and $A_2$ and then observe that you get a homotopy on their union.  Instead, you start with a space $X$ which can be decomposed into $A_1$ and $A_2$ and construct a homotopy separately on each one.

Comment: But I could counter that the "right" generalisation is to say: if $X$ and $M$ are topological spaces, if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are mutually separated subsets of  $X$ and if $f_1: A_1 \to M$ and  $f_2 : A_2 \to M$ are continuous functions, then $f_1$ and $f_2$ extend to a continuous function $f : A_1 \cup A_2 \to M$. (So I'm emphasising the criterion for the $A_i$ to be connected components of the subspace $A_1 \cup A_2$ and ignoring the "irrelevant' fact that the $f_i$ are homotopies, so my $A_i$ is $A_i \times [0, 1]$ in the original question.) The baby has too many aspects $\ddot{\smile}$.